# How to determine double points on a curve?

Tags: analysis, curves

I want to determine all the double points of the curve $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ that is given by $f(t) = (t^3 - t , t^2 - 1)$. Graphically, the output $(0,0)$ should occur twice, which gives $t = \pm 1$. However, this does not serve as a full proof I would assume. Unfortunately, I can't find any adequate information about this topic on the internet.

Hopefully some of you can help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: We should start with the definition of a double point.

Answer (score 1):

Graphing helps one discover true statements, such as the true statement "the output $(0,0)$ occurs twice, which gives $t=\pm 1$". Presumably you can verify the truth of that statement by explicit calculation; that calculation constitutes full proof of that statement.

However, you're not done. You have asked to determine ***all*** double points of that curve. Presumably your graph also tells you the true statement here: $t = \pm 1$ gives ***the only*** double point of the curve. This must still be proved.

So, you must take two unknown input values $s,t \in \mathbb R$, then form the equation
$$f(s)=f(t)
$$
$$(s^3-s,s^2-1) = (t^3-t,t^2-1)
$$
which breaks into two numerical equations
\begin{align*}
s^3 - s &= t^3 - t \\
s^2 - 1 &= t^2 - 1
\end{align*}
Thinking of this as a system of 2 equations in the  2 unknowns $s,t$, you must find all possible pairs of numbers $(s,t)$ which are simultaneous solutions of this pair of equations, *and* such that $s \ne t$ (these equations are of course always true when $s=t$, *but* that does not give you a double point). If your graph is not lying, the only solutions should be $s=1$, $t=-1$ and $s=-1,t=+1$ which gives just one double point.

Solving this system with algebra is not so hard, perhaps you can carry it through now?

Answer (score 0):

You might note that $x = t y$, so if $y \ne 0$, $t = x/y$ is uniquely determined.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it, just wanna check if this is correct. The second equations is $s^2 - 1 = t^2 - 1$. We can cancel the 1's and obtain $s^2 = t^2$. The only way we can get a double point from this is by concluding $s = -t$, which satisfies the equation and ensures that $s \neq t$, as long as $t \neq 0$. Plugging this into the first equation, we get $(-t)^3 - (-t) = -t^3 + t = t^3 - t$. This can be rearranged to $t^3 - t = 0$, which yields the solutions $t = 0,1$. We have noted above that $t$ cannot be $0$, thus $t = 1$ and $s = -1$ or the other way around.